# Is it possible to have two actions on a form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, button

I have a form that is currently setup to send data to Salesforce to collect the information. I would also like to have that same information go to Pardot for tracking purposes. I know forms normally only support one action, but im wondering if there is a way around this.

I tried adding in the code directly, which didnt work, and haven't been able to find any advice online that addresses this issue specifically

The Salesforce action portion is:

```
<div class="vc_row"><form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
```

and I would like to have this action added as well

```
<form action="http://go.cloudmybiz.com/l/547492/2019-06-03/dsmvd" method="post">
```

Comment: Form can have only one action. But you can change action-attribute with javascript.

Comment: you have two choices: 1) send it to your server and have your server send to both places; 2) write JavaScript that will send the form data to each place from within the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can submit 2 times if you do it with js. Example is taken from [here](http://form.guide/demos/multi-action-search/multi-action-search.php):

```
<form id="search" action="" method="get" onsubmit="javascript: return SubmitForm();">
<.... ret of the form>
</form>
```

and js:

```
function SubmitForm()
{
    showResultDiv();
    document.forms['search'].action='http://www.google.com/search';
    document.forms['search'].target='frame_result1';
    document.forms['search'].submit();

    document.forms['search'].action='http://www.bing.com/search';
    document.forms['search'].target='frame_result2';
    document.forms['search'].submit();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Send the form using JavaScript.

```html
<div class="vc_row">
    <form id="form" method="POST" onsubmit="sendData(event)">
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>

  <script>
    const sendData = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form"));

      fetch("https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8", { method: "POST", body: formData});
      fetch("http://go.cloudmybiz.com/l/547492/2019-06-03/dsmvd", { method: "POST", body: formData});
    };
  </script>
```