# Is it possible to have a form input text have two action outputs?

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

What I would like to do is be able to type something into the form input text field and press one of the buttons to search those results to my choosing: Google, Bing, DuckDuckGo or any others I want to add.

I have this:

```
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search?=">
<input type="reset" />
<input type="text" name="q" autocomplete="off" autofocus />
<input type="submit" value="Google Search"/>
<input type="submit" value="Bing Search"/>
</form>
```

I did see a post on here but unfortunately, the code wasn't complete:
[Is it possible to have two actions on a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433813/is-it-possible-to-have-two-actions-on-a-form)

That post showed

```
<form id="search" action="" method="get" onsubmit="javascript: return SubmitForm();">
<.... ret of the form>
</form>
```

and js

```
function SubmitForm()
{
    showResultDiv();
    document.forms['search'].action='http://www.google.com/search';
    document.forms['search'].target='frame_result1';
    document.forms['search'].submit();

    document.forms['search'].action='http://www.bing.com/search';
    document.forms['search'].target='frame_result2';
    document.forms['search'].submit();
    return false;
}
```

From the looks of it, it's possible but not sure how. Any ideas without PHP.  Just HTML and JS?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is not PHP it's JS.

Comment: My bad. I am trying to find a javascript version if it's possible.  :/

Comment: where do you want to get the output?

Comment: What do you mean?  I just want one search bar with search buttons to output it others. 
Example: Type in Hello World and press Google Search button and it sends you to Google site with the results.  If I press Bing search button it does the same to Bings search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using HTML only.

HTML

```
<form method="get"  target="blank" >
    <input type="reset" />
    <input type="text" name="q" autocomplete="off" autofocus />
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search" formaction="https://www.google.com/search"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Bing Search"  formaction="https://www.bing.com/search"/>
</form>
```

I found this [here](https://css-tricks.com/separate-form-submit-buttons-go-different-urls/)

Comment: That doesn't work doing it that way.
I would need to add the search  <input type="text"/> to the bing form.  But then it's two search bars and not one.   I need one form, one search bar and two-button outputs.   To bad, I suck at js. I know it needs to be done through that.  I just don't know now.

Comment: It should work now, I Just tested it. Please let me know.

Comment: I noticed you edited it.  Heck yeah, it works. Thanks, bud.  This will reduce the amount of code I have on my search page.   Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the best solutions but it work and its more secure than get method.
if called win2 before win  it will focus on google window.

```
<form id="form" role="search">
<input type="search" id="query" name="q" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search through site content">
<button>Search</button>
```

```
const f = document.getElementById('form');
const q = document.getElementById('query');
const google = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=+';
const bing = 'https://www.bing.com/search?q=+'
const site = '';
function submitted(event) {
event.preventDefault();
const urlG = google + site + '+' + q.value;
const urlB = bing + site + '+' + q.value;
const win = window.open(urlG, '_blank');
const win2 = window.open(urlB, '_blank');
win.focus();
win2.focus();
}
f.addEventListener('submit', submitted);
```

Comment: That's an interesting version and love more secure ways.  However, looks a bit more complicated for me but I still understand it enough that I can add to it.  I would need to test it with my startDictation() as it's stubborn and uses both the input type and form ID as well.

I'll work on the first two above yours and see how that goes first.  I still have Googles Autocomplete API to add and the startDictation() with other things as well to the search bar. As I have it right now, I need to reduce the code because I have 15 search bars in a slider with the same scripts on all search bars.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

HTML:

```
<form method="get"  target="blank" >
    <input type="reset" />
    <input id="the-text" type="text" name="q" autocomplete="off" autofocus />
    <button id="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
let search = document.getElementById('submit')
search.addEventListener("click", searchFunction);

function searchFunction() {
let searchText = document.getElementById('the-text').value;
window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q='+searchText)
window.open('https://www.bing.com/search?q='+searchText)
}
```

Unfortunately, browsers usually block 2 or more tabs opening at the same time. So, you can allow popups, and it will search on both Google & Bing, if popups are blocked, it will only show google's search result and Block Bing

Comment: I have a script that does the same on my search site.   My script is a bit more complicated so I like the simplistic layout that you have here.  I already added it to the top formaction layout and works well.  Thanks.   That's a step closer to rebuilding the one I have on my site.

Comment: For some reason, it makes a duplicate of the page as well.  Is there a way around it?